# Elegir ruta de exportación mediante ventana de windows

Tags: r

Así como para importar se puede usar `file.choose()`, hay algo similar para exportar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si, aunque solo para `Windows`, para abrir el dialogo de selección de un path, puedes usar `choose.dir()`, por ejemplo:

```
if (interactive() && .Platform$OS.type == "windows") {
  choose.dir(caption = "Elija la carpeta dónde salvar el archivo")
}
```

Por otro lado, también puedes reutilizar `file.choose()` para definir eventualmente un archivo nuevo:

```
file.choose(new  = TRUE)
```